# Use UI components drawn in Flash with Flash Builder (Flex)

Tags: flash, apache-flex, user-interface

I have some UI components (Toolbars and buttons) that I drew in Flash and was wondering how I can use it in Flex via the Flash Builder?

Comment: What format do you have the ToolBars and Buttons in?  Is it ActionScript 3?  Is it a SWF?  Is it a SWC?  In Flash Pro you can do something to convert the symbol into a Flex Component [or something similar].  But, it won't turn your asset into a Flex Button.

Answer (score 0):

cs4 & cs5 can export the flash movieclips as flex component.
check this [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSFD77A256-0DE1-46c7-86FB-CC4A8AE2EAA6.html) for prerequisites